# How to add sqlite3.dll for win rt as a reference?

Tags: c#, dll, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am building a Windows Store app that targets an ARM device (Windows RT tab), I installed the NuGet pkg SQLite-net and it works perfectly under x86 platform. But when I tested on the ARM device (note that platform target has been setup for ARM by this time), I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in
>   App1.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I have not been able to add the sqlite3.dll from the SQLite.org website, I tried to add as a "existing item", change its properties as content, copy always; but I keep getting the same error.

my Connection path is following:

```
// C#
     public static string sqlitedbPath = Path.Combine(
                Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "mydb.s3db");
```

I am sure I have the wrong DLL, but I am having I hard time to change it.

Does somebody has a good solution?

Comment: Assuming you've used "Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtime" from http://sqlite.org/download.html your and have it properly copied during build... Check if file is indeed copied (and correct one) to the target device.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but finally i made it work, i just downloaded the ones from msdn for Windows RT